# powershell / regex find string between words and trim them

Tags: string, powershell

I have sql files and they contain something like this:

```sql
INCLUDE (   [ShortName],
    [EMail],
    [Manager]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF
```

I need to trim the white spaces, tabs and new lines ONLY for content BETWEEN `INCLUDE` and `[space]WITH[space](PAD_INDEX`

so that the script changes to this:

```sql
INCLUDE([ShortName],[Object_Guid],[Active]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF
```

I appreciate your help

Comment: This doesn't sound like a task for regex. Also, why should the space right after `INCLUDE` be removed?

Comment: we are switching from SQL Management Studio Wizards to mssql-scripter, the latter introduces this noise and this is not good for source control, since it will see that thousands of files have changed, thanks.

Comment: No, I'm asking why you need this. You only want spaces between `INCLUDE[space](` and `[space]WITH[space](PAD_INDEX` be removed, but the original string contains `INCLUDE (` while the expected result has `INCLUDE(`. Why is this space removed? Shouldn't it remain intact as it does not lie between the two token, as described in the rule?

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking, I have edited the question.

Comment: This is not a PowerShell-specific issue. This a simple multi-replace statement, regardless of your language of choice. What did you try?  The RegEx websites are a solid place to try this sort of thing and learn RegEx. Lastly, what you are passing in will not result in what you say you want as the final output, because they are different strings. You can replace that however, to get that.

Comment: I have tried to adapt this: https://regex101.com/r/xcM6dt/1 but I don't know much of regex to succeed, thanks.

Comment: See my example as a RegEx template. Adjust as needed of course.

Comment: [Here you go](https://regex101.com/r/cw4DRz/1). I'm not writing an answer, nor will I take responsibility of any consequences, as I believe this kind of task should not be solved using pure regex (also, I don't know Powershell).

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment.

```
Clear-host
$MySqlString = 'INCLUDE (   [ShortName],
    [EMail],
    [Manager]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF'

$MySqlString -replace '\s+' -replace 'WITH', ' WITH ' -replace '=', ' = '
# Results
<#
INCLUDE([ShortName],[EMail],[Manager]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF
#>
```

So, this just replaces all multiple spaces with nothing then just takes any other specifics defined and manipulates just that string segment.